# How to return an iterator for single or multiple values in enum

Tags: rust, iterator

Consider the following code:

```rust
struct MediaKind;
struct OtherFields;

enum Media {
    Single(MediaKind),
    Group(Vec<MediaKind>, OtherFields),
}

impl Media {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &MediaKind> {
        match self {
            Self::Single(media) => [media].iter(),
            Self::Group(media_vec, _) => media_vec.iter(),
        }
    }
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:42
   |
11 | /         match self {
12 | |             Self::Single(media) => [media].iter(),
   | |                                    -------------- this is found to be of type `std::slice::Iter<'_, &MediaKind>`
13 | |             Self::Group(media_vec, _) => media_vec.iter(),
   | |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&MediaKind`, found struct `MediaKind`
14 | |         }
   | |_________- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, &MediaKind>`
              found struct `std::slice::Iter<'_, MediaKind>`
```

Because the `Group` arm may contain additional fields, replacing this entire `enum` with a `Vec` is not a preferred solution.

I have tried [`either`](https://crates.io/crates/either) crate to solve the problem in the following way:

```rust
fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &MediaKind> {
    use either::*;

    match self {
        Self::Single(media) => Left([media].into_iter()),
        Self::Group(media_vec, _) => Right(media_vec.iter()),
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to fix it without depending on an external crate.

[> Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89462debe62e6d2df083acd839fd48b4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, because one case is a slice iterator and the other is one element, you can use a trick: [`std::slice::from_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html):

```rust
fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &MediaKind> {
    match self {
        Self::Single(media) => std::slice::from_ref(media).iter(),
        Self::Group(media_vec, _) => media_vec.iter(),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c0159ecedd2ee8c6a813757c6db66fc).